# How to stay up to date in NLP and use the best approaches?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, text-classification, stanford-nlp

There are many fast advancements in NLP field, BERT, RoBERTa, ALBERT, and XLNe, and no one can check the news or papers daily. Is there any way or site that keeps track of all these new developments and possibly provides a link to the code? For example, if someone needs to use text summarization, the suggested approach would be X, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be up to date with the new advancements, a good way is skimming through the accepted papers of the major NLP conferences, namely [ACL](https://2021.aclweb.org/program/accept/), [EMNLP](https://2021.emnlp.org/), and the regional EACL, NAACL, AACL.

If you want even more information, you can skim through the papers uploaded to the arxiv. One way to do that is via Twitter, by following bots that tweet papers in specific areas. For instance [this bot](https://twitter.com/arxiv_cscl) tweets the papers uploaded to the computational linguistics (CL) category.

If you just want to check the best approaches when you are to decide how to approach a problem, then a good option is [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/). It is a website with the state of the art in different areas (not only NLP), with rankings of the results for different benchmarks, together with links to the paper and source code. For instance, you can have a look at the machine translation section [here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/machine-translation).

Comment: Thanks. There are thousands of papers from these conferences, so it is almost impossible to skim.  The bot that you mentioned posed 120k tweets. That's a lot of noise. Papers with code could be useful, but it seems things are not being updated frequently. For example, text classification https://paperswithcode.com/task/text-classification. A website or a book with simple visualization or if-else would be great!

Answer (score 1):

https://nlpprogress.com/ aims to provide pointers to the state of the art papers and datasets for the main NLP tasks.

It seems to be updated regularly so far. However it depends on the efforts of volunteers so there's no guarantee about completeness or future updates.

Comment: I saw it, but it seems not very up to date. BERT is still not in text classification https://github.com/sebastianruder/NLP-progress/blob/master/english/text_classification.md

Comment: @ThomasLee keeping a site up to date with a research field as vast and fast-evolving as NLP is a very time-consuming job. Unless some people or institutions are ready to pay for somebody to do this job, it's not very surprising that only imperfect solutions are available for free.